# VS WebTest errors when references have dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, msloadtest

The below error is thrown when a Visual Studio Web and Load Testing Performance Project references assemblies with dependencies.  The error is thrown when attempting to convert the webtest to code, when attempting to insert a plugin, or when attempting to insert a request plugin.

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.53.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of it's dependencies. 
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

In this example, I have added only two dependencies.  Selenium.WebDriver v2.53.1.0 and Selenium.WebDriver.Support v2.53.1.0.  Support is dependent on WebDriver.  Both were added as references (via Selenium's nuget packages) and included in the solution.  Both get copied to output directory. Both have been verified to not be blocked (ran `Unblock-File -Path $pathToReference` to be sure).  Modified DevEnv.exe.config to add `<LoadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>` to the runtime section.

I can reproduce this in a bare bones solution, which can be found on [github](https://github.com/nrf1552/WebTestError).

Has anyone encountered this and found a way to work around it? It's very inconvenient to have to remove the references in order to use the plugin and convert to code features, then add them back.

Comment: Assuming the plugins and the `.webtest` are in different projects in the solution then **all** the references need to be added to both projects.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHHH, but it's just a single project.  Even the sample project I provided has the references, a single webtest, and that is it.

Comment: I thin you need to [edit] the question to explain in more detail how your project and the solution are structured. Linking to GitHub to provide a description is against the spirit of Stack Overflow, questions and answers here should be self contained. Links elsewhere are allowed but only for filling in the fine details.